# how to call range::-webkit-slider-runnable-track?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I need to call `.range::-webkit-slider-runnable-track` using either jquery or javascript so I can make some changes over to it's background and do other implementations over it.

To be precise I am currently using

```
$('<style>.myrange::-webkit-slider-runnable-track{background:linear-gradient(to right, white'+val+'%, #bbb '+val+'%);}</style>').appendTo('head');
```

This works pretty much fine, but the problem is that I'm calling `.myrange::-webkit-slider-runnable-track` like couple of thousands of times which every time it appends to head my range gets to face some performance issue and so.

I would really appreciate if some one tell how to do this with something like `$('.myrange::-webkit-slider-runnable-track').css("background", "black");`

Question Update:

```
<input type="range" value="0" min="0" max="100" id="myrange" class="myrange"/>
```

This `range` has connected to a video which track the video duration and changes the color of the track up to the point that the video has been watched.

And to do the coloring of the range tracker this is what I am doing:

```
vid.addEventListener('progress', function() {
    var range = 0;
    var bf = this.buffered;
    var time = this.currentTime;

    while(!(bf.start(range) <= time && time <= bf.end(range))) {
        range += 1;
    }
    var loadStartPercentage = bf.start(range) / this.duration;
    var loadEndPercentage = bf.end(range) / this.duration;
   var loadPercentage = loadEndPercentage -      loadStartPercentage;

   val = loadPercentage*100;
   thmpos = $('.vidskb_r').val();
   var style = $("<style>", {type:"text/css"}).appendTo("head");
   style.text('.vidskb_r::-webkit-slider-runnable-track{background:linear-gradient(to right, #ff7e20 '+thmpos+'%, #fff '+thmpos+'%, #fff '+val+'%, #bbb '+val+'%);}');

});
```

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append `css` text to a single `<style>` element, substitute `.text()` for `.append()`

Note, you do not need to create a new `<style>` element at each iteration of a loop or event handler. Create `<style>` element once outside of loop or event handler and use a variable to reference the single `<style>` element within loop or event handler.

```
// create and append `<style>` element to `<head>` once, here
// before attaching `progress` event to `vid`, and outside
// of `progress` event handler
var style = $("<style>", {type:"text/css"}).appendTo("head");

vid.addEventListener('progress', function() {
    var range = 0;
    var bf = this.buffered;
    var time = this.currentTime;

    while(!(bf.start(range) <= time && time <= bf.end(range))) {
        range += 1;
    }
    var loadStartPercentage = bf.start(range) / this.duration;
    var loadEndPercentage = bf.end(range) / this.duration;
   var loadPercentage = loadEndPercentage -      loadStartPercentage;

   val = loadPercentage*100;
   thmpos = $('.vidskb_r').val();

   style.text('.vidskb_r::-webkit-slider-runnable-track{background:linear-gradient(to right, #ff7e20 '+thmpos+'%, #fff '+thmpos+'%, #fff '+val+'%, #bbb '+val+'%);}');

});
```

Comment: So it will be like this: `var style = $("<style>").appendTo("head");style.append(".myrange::-webkit-slider-runnable-track{background:linear-gradient(to right, white "+val+"%, #bbb "+val+"%);}");` If so Then it is still appending the style to head over and over, which I can see that by inspecting my browser head element.

Comment: You can substitute `.text()` for `.append()`

Comment: I updated my question you can read the update in my question!

Comment: @akdsfjakls Have you substituted `.text()` for `.append()`? See updated post.

Comment: @akdsfjakls No changes in which way?

Comment: It's still appending to head over and over, each time the `val` value changes. which cause me to face performance issue.

Comment: Can you see this: https://postimg.org/image/he6cgh0sv/ it's my head scout

Comment: You only need to call `var style = $("<style>", {type:"text/css"}).appendTo("head");` once, outside of loop. Use cached selector `style` to reference `<style>` element within loop.

Comment: I posted my whole video handler you can see it in my question update, And  you said I only need to call .... once, do you mean I should create a new function input my `style.text` and call it in my `progress` handler?

Comment: Thanks Man, you are awesome, It's working just perfect.