# HTML DOM Style backgroundImage Property for a Slider range

Tags: javascript, html, css, rangeslider

I have an slider range, I want to change it's background-image property using javascript. I tried the following script

```
document.getElementById("range").style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(to top,#fafa6e,#f9f96e,#f8f86e,#f6f76d,#f5f56d,#f4f46d,#f3f36d,#f1f26d,#f0f16c,#efef6c,#eeee6c,#eced6c,#ebec6c,#eaeb6b,#e8e96b,#e7e86b,#e6e76b,#e4e66b,#e3e46a,#e2e36a,#e0e26a,#dfe16a,#dedf6a,#dcde69,#dbdd69,#dadb69,#d8da69,#d7d969,#d5d868,#d4d668,#d2d568,#d1d368,#d0d267,#ced167,#cdcf67,#cbce67,#cacd67,#c8cb66,#c7ca66,#c5c866,#c3c766,#c2c566,#c0c465,#bfc365,#bdc165,#bcc065,#babe64,#b8bd64,#b7bb64,#b5ba64,#b3b864,#b2b663,#b0b563,#aeb363,#acb263,#abb063,#a9ae62,#a7ad62,#a5ab62,#a3a962,#a1a861,#a0a661,#9ea461,#9ca261,#9aa160,#989f60,#969d60,#949b60,#929960,#8f975f,#8d965f,#8b945f,#89925f,#87905e,#848e5e,#828c5e,#808a5e,#7d885e,#7b855d,#78835d,#76815d,#737f5d,#717d5c,#6e7a5c,#6b785c,#68755c,#65735b,#62705b,#5f6e5b,#5c6b5b,#59685a,#55665a,#51635a,#4e605a,#4a5d59,#455a59,#415659,#3c5359,#375058,#314c58,#2a4858)";
```

But it does not work. Can someone please gives me some hints how can I do it?
Here is the example that I am working on

https://codepen.io/am2222/pen/KKwZBNW

thanks

P.S: I do not want to use jquery or other js libraries

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49123541/how-to-add-css-to-webkit-slider-runnable-track-using-javascript

Comment: @PedroEstrada thanks but I do not want to use jquery. I want to use native js

Answer (score 0):

Converting what was done here from jQuery to vanilla js: [how to add CSS to -webkit-slider-runnable-track using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49123541/how-to-add-css-to-webkit-slider-runnable-track-using-javascript)

You come to this:

```
var newScript = document.createElement("style");
var content = document.createTextNode(`input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top,#fafa6e,#f9f96e,#f8f86e,#f6f76d,#f5f56d,#f4f46d,#f3f36d,#f1f26d,#f0f16c,#efef6c,#eeee6c,#eced6c,#ebec6c,#eaeb6b,#e8e96b,#e7e86b,#e6e76b,#e4e66b,#e3e46a,#e2e36a,#e0e26a,#dfe16a,#dedf6a,#dcde69,#dbdd69,#dadb69,#d8da69,#d7d969,#d5d868,#d4d668,#d2d568,#d1d368,#d0d267,#ced167,#cdcf67,#cbce67,#cacd67,#c8cb66,#c7ca66,#c5c866,#c3c766,#c2c566,#c0c465,#bfc365,#bdc165,#bcc065,#babe64,#b8bd64,#b7bb64,#b5ba64,#b3b864,#b2b663,#b0b563,#aeb363,#acb263,#abb063,#a9ae62,#a7ad62,#a5ab62,#a3a962,#a1a861,#a0a661,#9ea461,#9ca261,#9aa160,#989f60,#969d60,#949b60,#929960,#8f975f,#8d965f,#8b945f,#89925f,#87905e,#848e5e,#828c5e,#808a5e,#7d885e,#7b855d,#78835d,#76815d,#737f5d,#717d5c,#6e7a5c,#6b785c,#68755c,#65735b,#62705b,#5f6e5b,#5c6b5b,#59685a,#55665a,#51635a,#4e605a,#4a5d59,#455a59,#415659,#3c5359,#375058,#314c58,#2a4858)
}`);
newScript.appendChild(content);
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(newScript);
```

Comment: thanks. But in this case I am adding an style manually to the page. so for each range slider I have to add a new style to the page? Is this the only way?

Answer (score 0):

You can just assign the current background color of your input slider in your css to a [CSS variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var) and then use JavaScript to change that variable at anytime using the [setProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/setProperty) method.

---

Check and run the following Code Snippet for a practical example of the above approach:

```js
//assign the root element of your document to a variable
let root = document.documentElement;

//change the value of "--rangeColor" accordingly
root.style.setProperty('--rangeColor', "linear-gradient(to top,#fafa6e,#f9f96e,#f8f86e,#f6f76d,#f5f56d,#f4f46d,#f3f36d,#f1f26d,#f0f16c,#efef6c,#eeee6c,#eced6c,#ebec6c,#eaeb6b,#e8e96b,#e7e86b,#e6e76b,#e4e66b,#e3e46a,#e2e36a,#e0e26a,#dfe16a,#dedf6a,#dcde69,#dbdd69,#dadb69,#d8da69,#d7d969,#d5d868,#d4d668,#d2d568,#d1d368,#d0d267,#ced167,#cdcf67,#cbce67,#cacd67,#c8cb66,#c7ca66,#c5c866,#c3c766,#c2c566,#c0c465,#bfc365,#bdc165,#bcc065,#babe64,#b8bd64,#b7bb64,#b5ba64,#b3b864,#b2b663,#b0b563,#aeb363,#acb263,#abb063,#a9ae62,#a7ad62,#a5ab62,#a3a962,#a1a861,#a0a661,#9ea461,#9ca261,#9aa160,#989f60,#969d60,#949b60,#929960,#8f975f,#8d965f,#8b945f,#89925f,#87905e,#848e5e,#828c5e,#808a5e,#7d885e,#7b855d,#78835d,#76815d,#737f5d,#717d5c,#6e7a5c,#6b785c,#68755c,#65735b,#62705b,#5f6e5b,#5c6b5b,#59685a,#55665a,#51635a,#4e605a,#4a5d59,#455a59,#415659,#3c5359,#375058,#314c58,#2a4858)");
```

```css
:root {
  --rangeColor: #3071a9;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: var(--rangeColor);
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.1px solid #010101;
}
```

```html
<input id="range" type="range" />
```

Comment: thanks. I like this method.but what if I am making the range sliders themselves using js? I guess this method does not work since each slider needs to have a diffrent background-color